# Is there any Japanese anime with a Korean OP or ED?

Tags: anime-production, theme-song

I like Korean music and anime.

Is there any Japanese anime with a Korean OP or ED?

Comment: Maybe, if you watch the Korean version of an anime.

Answer (score 2):

I know of anime OSTs created by Korean artists but not in the Korean language. If you follow Korean music, you shall know about TVXQ creating three OSTs for *One Piece*

- [OP OP 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxzTZeDL6ag)
- [OP ED 17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOAzUviWg44)

Also, BoA has created the *Inuyasha* OP.

- [Inuyasha Opening by BoA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GMu9kv7wIQ)

*Ao no Exorcist* OP was created by 2PM, I could get the K-pop vibes from it when I first listened to it.

These are the only ones I know of, anime is pretty popular in Korea so I am sure there are more, feel free to do more research.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the OP/ED of an anime, it is more likely to find Opening and the Endings that is produced by Korean artist (singing in Japanese) than featuring actual Korean songs.

In the 15th Opening of *Fairy Tail*, *Masayume Chasing*, it is sung by a Korean singer who goes by the name of BoA. Here is [the YouTube link](https://youtu.be/G0gD9jzYtEA) to the song in short ver.

As for another anime which is called *Beezlebub*, the 4th Opening of the series is sung by a Korean Group MBLAQ, Baby U. The particular opening does has the K-pop genre-like vibe.

- TVXQ with *One Piece* ”Share the World”
- 2PM with *Ao no Exorcist* with “Take Off”
- Secret with a Naruto spinoff called “Twinkle Twinkle”
- And quite a handful of Korean artist/group

Overall, It is more likely that a Korean artist would produce an OP/ED in Japanese instead of Korean as it is usually will be as a Japanese single.

Answer (score 1):

I know of one anime that has a Korean ending song. It's from *Black Blood Brothers*, the song is *Shinkirou* by LOVEHOLIC.

This link is the oldest link I could find, enjoy! [Black Blood Brothers Ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZsm0W-hnNQ)

Answer (score 0):

There is one I know but only a movie. *Pokémon the Movie: Volcanion and the Mechanical Marvel* OST is sung by the Korean girl group G-Friend.

Title: *Letter Inside Pocket*.

There is even a music video:
https://www.allkpop.com/article/2016/12/g-friend-sings-letter-inside-pocket-for-pokmon-the-movie-volcanion-and-the-mechanical-marvel